# jquery - no effect of 'removeAttr'

Tags: jquery, onclick

This code is a direct copy-paste from the [jquery#faq page](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_a_form_element.3F)

```
<select id="x" style="width:200px;">
   <option>one</option>
   <option>two</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Disable" onclick="$('#x').attr('disabled','disabled')"/>
<input type="button" value="Enable" onclick="$('#x').removeAttr('disabled')"/>
```

The `select` option list is getting disabled on first click to `disable`, but not getting enabled again on clicking the `Enable` button.

Please let me know, what is wrong with above piece of code?

I am using Chrome 23.0.1271.64 on windows.

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd7GC/) (Chromium/linux)

Comment: Does it work here? http://jsfiddle.net/Anrse/ It works for me on Chrome on Windows. (Last version).

Comment: @student yes. the jsFiddle is working. I guess there is some bug on the jquery faq page then. Can you plz try on the above faw link in the post? Does that work?

Comment: faq page is broken because it uses this `onclick="$('#x').attr('disabled','')"` instead of `removeAttr('disabled')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about there being a bug on the official jQuery page. Viewing the source for that page shows that this is the actual code:

```
<select id="x" style="width:200px;" disabled="disabled">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="$('#x').attr('disabled','disabled')" value="Disable">
<input type="button" onclick="$('#x').attr('disabled','')" value="Enable">
```

As you can see, the `onclick` code is incorrect; to enable a control (according to the jQuery FAQ) the `disabled` attribute should either be set to `false` or removed using `$(..).removeAttr()`.

Answer (score 3):

As of jQuery 1.7, use .prop instead:

```
$('#x').prop('disabled', true);
$('#x').prop('disabled', false);
```

Although, as mentioned by others it seems it appears to work correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/K5MRf/

Comment: You should really use `$('#x').prop('disabled', true);` and `$('#x').prop('disabled', false);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the jQuery page

They say to use `$('#x').attr('disabled')` but if you see the actual code that runs, it is `$('#x').attr('disabled','')`

This sets the `disabled` attribute to an empty string. But that means that the attribute remains, and the correct usage of this attribute is for the element to be considered disabled if the attribute exists at all.

The proper way to do it is to use `.prop` and use directly `true`/`false` values with it as @Kurt showed..